# How to group-by in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like [Original] in below.
I want to sum by group-by field like [result].
Does anyone have an idea to make this query?
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
WITH t1 as (
      SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 2 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 3 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 4 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 5 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 6 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 7 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 3 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 8 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 9 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM t1




[Original Data]
ID  FIELD   VAL
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   A   1
4   B   2
5   B   2
6   B   1
7   A   3
8   A   2
9   A   1


[Result]
ID  FIELD   VAL
1   A   4
4   B   5
7   A   6
```

Comment: which query did you already try and what was the problem with it?

Comment: Of course, Oracle does have an idea, a description, and moreover, [some examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2066419) right in the doc section on [`GROUP BY clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2182483). Please, provide a description on what is your issue.

Comment: By using normal group by, it returns only two records with A, B. In this problem, I want to handle the two groups of 'A'. Thanks to Tejash, MT0, GMB, now I know that this is called gaps and island problem. Thanks you for your joining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is island and gap issue and you can use analytical function as follows:

```
SQL> WITH t1 as (
  2        SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
  3  UNION SELECT 2 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
  4  UNION SELECT 3 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
  5  UNION SELECT 4 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
  6  UNION SELECT 5 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
  7  UNION SELECT 6 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
  8  UNION SELECT 7 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 3 AS VAL FROM dual
  9  UNION SELECT 8 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
 10  UNION SELECT 9 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
 11  )
 12  SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, FIELD, SUM(VAL)
 13    FROM (SELECT T1.*,
 14     SUM(CASE WHEN LAG_FIELD = FIELD THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
 15  OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS SM
 16    FROM (SELECT T1.*,
 17     LAG(FIELD) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS LAG_FIELD
 18    FROM t1
 19  ) T1
 20  )
 21  GROUP BY FIELD, SM
 22  ORDER BY 1;

        ID F   SUM(VAL)
---------- - ----------
         1 A          4
         4 B          5
         7 A          6

SQL>
```

Comment: It is awesome to do reverse engineering of the problem by taking result data and input data without any description. I really admire this solution and your skills, great!

Comment: It's really nice approach. I love the way you did. It's a brilliant solution without any new functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a gaps-and-islands problem. I think the simplest approach here is to use the difference between row numbers to identify groups of adjacent rows:

```
select min(id) as id, field, sum(val) as val
from (
    select t1.*,
        row_number() over(order by id) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by field order by id) rn2
    from t1
) t
group by field, rn1 - rn2
order by min(id)
```

*If* `id` is always incrementing without gaps, this is even simpler:

```
select min(id) as id, field, sum(val) as val
from (
    select t1.*,
        row_number() over(partition by field order by id) rn
    from t1
) t
group by field, id - rn
order by min(id)
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I found that this is gaps and island problem. It's really great joy for me that I have approached many people's concerns. Your solution is very nice as like others.  I was very impressed with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can do it quite simply using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
WITH t1 as (
      SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 2 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 3 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 4 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 5 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 6 AS ID, 'B' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 7 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 3 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 8 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 2 AS VAL FROM dual
UNION SELECT 9 AS ID, 'A' AS FIELD, 1 AS VAL FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM   t1
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY id
  MEASURES
    FIRST( id ) AS id,
    FIRST( field ) AS field,
    SUM( val ) AS total
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN( same_field+ )
  DEFINE same_field AS FIRST(field) = field 
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID | FIELD | TOTAL
> -: | :---- | ----:
>  1 | A     |     4
>  4 | B     |     5
>  7 | A     |     6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d61a19272b628ebbc55f46d2cd49c549)*

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Even though my oracle is 11, the fiddle show that you are right. I appreciate your great answer.